# Same query with different parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have a query to calculate a sum over last 12 months like:

```
select part_no, 
       count(part_no) r12 
  from t1 
 where (t1.created<=sysdate and t1.created>=add_months(sysdate,-12)
```

Is it possible to create a query that also shows rolling 6 and rolling 3 in the same query like:

```
part_no r12 r6 r3
-----------------
100     8   2  1
200     12  1  0
300     10  4  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know `COUNT` of all items for last 12, 6 and 3 you can change your query as follows.

```
SELECT part_no
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.created <= sysdate
                        AND t1.created >= add_months(sysdate, -12) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) r12
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.created <= sysdate
                        AND t1.created >= add_months(sysdate, -6) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) r6
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.created <= sysdate
                        AND t1.created >= add_months(sysdate, -3) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) r3
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY part_no
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most feasible approach.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can try something like this:

```
SELECT part_no, 
       SUM( IF(t1.created>=add_months(sysdate,-12), 1, 0) ) r12,
       SUM( IF(t1.created>=add_months(sysdate,-6), 1, 0) ) r6,
       SUM( IF(t1.created>=add_months(sysdate,-3), 1, 0) ) r3
FROM t1 
WHERE t1.created<=sysdate
GROUP BY part_no
```

Comment: Sorry for my English, but I try to explain: it's possible when one row will fall into all three columns

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate date difference (in months) in subquery and group by it. But don't forget about query performance.